# android non unique view id

Tags: android, xml, listener, uniqueidentifier

I have a `LinearLayout` that contains a `ViewStub` which points to a `ViewFlipper`. The `ViewStub` is *statically assigned its layout reference values on startup (currently, next version will be dynamic). Located within the `ViewFlipper` are 10 `RelativeLayouts` each with its own assortment of buttons, edittexts, textviews, etc.

On about half of those pages is a `TogggleButton`

```
<ToggleButton 
    android:id="@+id/dontNeed" 
    android:textOn="DON'T NEED" 
    android:textOff="DON'T NEED" 
    android:layout_width="200dp" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_height="100dp" 
    android:textSize="36sp" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:background="#AA0000" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp" 
/>
```

Specific views, when used, will assign recommendation values to others based on some calculations. This button well let the system know the user does not require any information from the current page.

If I have this same button on many pages, does it require a unique ID for each page? This is based in terms of attaching listeners to each of the buttons. Does each button "`dontNeed`" require a separate ID or will attaching the non unique id to a listener use all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I have this same button on many pages, does it require a unique ID for each page?

That depends on where and how you are calling `findViewById()` to retrieve the widget. The widget ID must be unique enough that, when you call `findViewById()` on something (the activity, the ViewFlipper, a child container within the `ViewFlipper`, etc.), that you are guaranteed to get your desired widget back.

> will attaching the non unique id to a listener use all of them?

You do not attach an "id to a listener", "non unique" or otherwise. You attach a listener to a widget.

Comment: My question was not meant to be taken as a literal translation. I understand that when I use findViewById(), it returns a view (not a widget). I was attempting to ask, if a View exists within many separate  parent Views, am I required to maintain separate objects to attach listeners to, or am I able to maintain a single object?

Comment: @scott.smart: "My question was not meant to be taken as a literal translation" -- then why did you write it that way? "if a View exists within many separate parent Views" -- this is not possible. In a tree structure, a child has one parent. "am I required to maintain separate objects to attach listeners to" -- each live widget is an object, whether you reference it or not. Each widget needs to have a set-listener method called upon it if you want to respond to that widget's events. Whether you have the widgets share a common listener object or not is up to you.

Comment: @scott.smart: "I understand that when I use findViewById(), it returns a view (not a widget)." -- views *are* widgets. A widget is an instance of some subclass of `View`, though the term "widget" tends not to be used for containers like `LinearLayout`.